# Ubuntu 20.04 . Desktop Sharing

Tags: 20.04, sharing

I can not find a setting that enables remote access to the desktop in Ubuntu 20.04. In previous releases, it was in the settings. This one isn’t.

Comment: I found it under Settings/Sharing.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNalldDf5YIYzgAalXtmZjQfkjIja9C6/view?usp=sharing    
Unfortunately, I do not have a "Share screen" item in the menu

Comment: echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the [Vino package](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en) in Ubuntu 20.04:

> You must have the Vino package installed for Screen Sharing to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and vino is installed.

if I start the program myself, I can connect to it remotely

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:1
```

But I must start it myself. It does not matter that sharing is enabled in the Settings UI.